# MySQL Master-Master Replication Slave Thread Issue

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-replication

I'm currently trying to set up Master-Master MySQL replication between 2 servers, but I'm encountering an unusual issue.

I'm getting this error on my MySQL log:

```
Slave: Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist Error_code: 1146
```

And I'm seeing that this table 'pma_recent' indeed doesn't exist on this particular server, but on the other server I'm setting up this replication with it does.

Any ideas as to what I should be doing here? Should I be looking into adding this table on the server getting the error, or removing it on the other?

Comment: What steps did you take to initially set up replication?  It seems like the servers are out of sync in some way, which is a bad thing when you're trying to get them replicating to each other with the same data set.

Comment: I used this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication Starting with the server that's working correctly.

Comment: Looks like that guide relies on there being absolutely no data in the database when replication is set up, as it doesn't handle an initial import of a data dump.  Try adding the `mysqldump` and import before you start the slave?  See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto-existingdata.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd explain how I solved this issue for anyone in the future that has the same issue.

So the issue was that both of my servers had been setup 4 months apart. So the older one was lacking some of the tables that the newer one had; as when setting up the server, it was setup on an older version of PHPMyAdmin. When updating PHPMyAdmin, these new tables weren't created; which seems like a major error on their part.

The solution was to import these new tables, so that both servers had exactly the same PHPMyAdmin tables. Any variation seemed to cause major issues with replication. To do this, you need to import 'create_tables.sql' on the older version of PHPMyAdmin.

This is located at:

```
./usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples
```

Well hopefully this was helpful to someone, it certainly took me a long time to fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

edit in .cnf file by the command :

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

replicate-ignore-table=phpmyadmin.pma_recent
replicate-ignore-table=phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs
replicate-ignore-table=phpmyadmin.pma_column_info
//mention whichever table is throwing error
```

Then,
- restart mysql
- stop slave
- start slave
- show slave status